# The process could not bulk copy into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, sqlbulkcopy

I have established a Transactional Replication between two cities.
I created the publisher successfully and the snapshot was created successfully afte 11 hours (as my DB is 160GB) as well.

now when I create the subscriber which is a new empty database, I could see that the publisher generates all the Tables,Store procedures, functions etc and then copies the tables' data (the tables that have small number of rows)

but when it wants to copy the tables with thousands of rows, I got the following error message and it just retries:

*I use SQL Server 2008R2 and my Servers are 2008R2 as well my Network is over LAN*

> Error messages: The process could not bulk copy into table
>   '"dbo"."Process"'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL0)
>
> metadata query failed
>
> TCP Provider: The specified network name is no longer available.
>   (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 64)Get
>
> Communication link failure (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 64)Get
>
> metadata query failed (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 64)Get help:
>
> Communication link failure (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number:
>   -2147467259)Get

Comment: This is a network related error.  Are you replicating over LAN, WAN, or VPN?  You will likely need to have a network admin check the links.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams See my update. it is on LAN

Comment: The error message clearly states it is a communication link failure.  It could be the network card of the publisher or subscriber, switch, or something else.  Best to have a network admin check the links.